# MLR3 using data transforms in bootstrapping hit an error

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics-bootstrap, mlr3

I'm trying to use bootstrapping resampling as my cross-validation in mlr3, and have been tracking down the cause of an error:

> Error in as_data_backend.data.frame(backend, primary_key = row_ids) :
> Assertion on 'primary_key' failed: Contains duplicated values, position 2.

The position changes (likely the first repeated row). Based on the error message I first thought it was an issue having rownames included, so I set those as the col_type$name, and also tried removing rownames from the data before creating the task (no luck!).

In trying to create a reprex, I narrowed it down to transform pipe operators like 'scale' and 'pca' as the cause:

```
library("mlr3verse")

task <- tsk('sonar')

pipe = po('scale') %>>%
  po(lrn('classif.rpart'))

ps <- ParamSet$new(list(
  ParamDbl$new("classif.rpart.cp", lower = 0, upper = 0.05)
))

glrn <- GraphLearner$new(pipe) 

glrn$predict_type <- "prob"

bootstrap <- rsmp("bootstrap", ratio = 1, repeats = 5)

instance <- TuningInstanceSingleCrit$new(
  task = task,
  learner = glrn,
  resampling = bootstrap,
  measure = msr("classif.auc"),
  search_space = ps,
  terminator = trm("evals", n_evals = 100)
)

tuner <- tnr("random_search")
tuner$optimize(instance)
```

I've also tried grid search instead of random, different learners, including the flag "duplicated_ids = TRUE" in rsmp, with no luck. Changing to CV cross validation, however, does fix the problem.

For reference, in the full pipe/graph I am trying different feature filters and learners to identify candidate pipelines.

Comment: This looks like a bug. I recommend posting an issue https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues.

Comment: I am really interested was this resolved?

Comment: I haven't submitted it as an issue, so not that I know of.

Comment: I ran into the same problem. I posted a bug report: https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3/issues/833